# Monitor wake-up is slower than computer boot

Tags: display, displayport

I have a xiaomi 34 inch ultrawide monitor. I don't turn it off, but of course it goes to sleep when it is not being used.

When I turn on my computer every morning the following happens:

1. I get a black screen for 20 second
2. after this the monitor works perfectly and it shows my fully booted computer with all the programs I need opened and ethernet up.

My question: Is there anything I can do to make my monitor wake-up faster than it takes my computer to fully boot and autostartup all my programs?

I am using the display-port cable that came with the monitor, I am fairly confident that the problem is the monitor wakes up too slow and that the image does get sent to the monitor on time.

One small inconvenience is that I don't get to see the bios splash screen ever so I got to blindly spam F2 to get into bios (thit isn't really an issue though).

In case it matters I have a prime b450m-a asus motherboard with a rx560 graphics card.

Thank you very much and best regards.

Comment: Which refresh rate are you using? There are reports that this happens when using a rate higher than 120Hz, some even needed to get it down to 60Hz.

Comment: 120hz I'm going to test that out !

Comment: Tried it at 50hz but didn't get any difference. In any case the 120hz only kicks in after xorg starts (I think).

Comment: I saw one report where this monitor was returned twice and the problem happened with all three.

Comment: Yeah maybe it's just slow to wake-up It's kind of a blessing in disguise I guess I'll stop trying to make my boot blazing fast for a couple of years :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this problem as well.  Monitor is slow to wake up with DP but does OK with HDMI.  One work around it manually wake up the monitor (power it off and on from sleep) then start the PC.  It should give you your boot menu.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).